# calculating 2d screen area of 3d object after translate and rotate

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, rendering, openframeworks

I'm making a crossword application, each square will be selectable by touching it. I can take a cube, translate it and rotate it, but how can i calculate the vertices of the resulting 2d shape on the screen that it makes?

I'm using openframeworks that uses OpenGL, here's some example code, this texture may eventually be mapped onto the top surface of a simple cube. what I'd like to do is fill a vector full of the 2d shapes that make it onto the screen that are these touchable surfaces. either that or turn the touch into a ray and cast it into the world and work out if it intercepts any of the touchable surfaces of these cubes.

```
ofTexture  texScreen

ofPushMatrix();
ofSetHexColor(0xffffff);
ofTranslate(550,300,100);
glRotatef(counter, 0.1f, 0.03f, 0);
texScreen.draw(0, 0, 0);
ofPopMatrix();
```

Comment: That's not enough information. Rotation and translation are generally part of your modelview matrix, but that only gets you to view-space. The projection matrix takes you from view-space (AKA eye-space) to clip-space and then immediately after coordinates are divided by W to get to NDC-space. From there you use the viewport mapping to go to window-space (AKA screen-space). You are missing projection and viewport in this scenario, I would suggest reading [this](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html) for an overview.

Comment: I completely agree. you can simplify things by getting the board corner points in screen space and interpolate mouse position from that (via basis vectors) (assuming your crossword game is on planar board) also another way is use OpenGL for selection ... https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/selection.htm